# SQL Server: Rename column after dropping another one without GO

Tags: sql-server

Is this the right way to make sure that a column of my table is only renamed after another column is dropped?

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl DROP COLUMN tmpcol
EXEC sp_rename 'mytbl.tmpcol2', 'tmpcol', 'COLUMN'
```

I'm not allowed to use the "GO"-separator.
I've tested the above two lines for a bunch of different table-sizes.
It worked as I expected, i.e. the 2nd Line is only executed after the 1st one.
But how can I make sure, that this will be the preferred execution plan for any table?

Is this guaranteed by `EXEC` ?

Comment: SQL is sequential; the second statement will never be run before the first.

Comment: But don't forget to separate your different SQL commands with the ";" (semicolon)

Comment: @Larnu: Well, I've made another observation with ms-sql. For instance "alter table mytbl add somecol int;" followed by "update mytbl set somecol=1;" will result in 'Invalid column name somecol' if I try to execute this in single batch without the "GO"-separator

Comment: Correct, because the batch is parsed *before*  it is run, and at that point the column `somecol` didn't exist. Only some DDL statements are noted and referenced later in the same batch by the compiler. An `ALTER TABLE` statement is not one of them. The data engine didn't try to run the `UPDATE` statement *before* the `ALTER TABLE`, it didn't run either of them, as the entire batch was not run.

Comment: _i'm not allowed to use the "GO"-separator._ Yes you are but GO isn't a tsql command. It is a batch separator used by some tools (e.g., SSMS) to separate batches within a larger script of multiple statements. If you meant that you are executing this from an application, then it is YOU the developer that must manage the batches correctly

Comment: ok, got it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server run query line-by-line, there is no chance that `EXEC` can run before `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: If the first line errors, the batch'll be aborted, and then the 2nd line won't be run at all.

Comment: I'm so dumb! I forgot such a simple thing.. Thanks for reminding me. Also, answer corrected :)